# create a form action with html in yii

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I have the following from in yii.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

I would like to to the following:

```
<form action="/protected/plans.php" method="POST">
```

However, that doesn't work. What is the proper way for providing the link in the form action in yii. Thank you for the help.

Comment: please be more specific then "that doesn't work"

Comment: Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read protected or not readable by server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access from url to files in `/protected` folder. It's private forlder to use only on server side. Move you file `plans.php` to project's root directory or create another folder near `/protected`.

Answer (score 0):

As **SiZE** said, You can't access the files inside `protected`, because yii projects have a `.htaccess` file in the root and this file has `deny form all` line. First way is to move file out of `protected` folder. But I think it's not a good choice at all. You are using an **MVC Framework** and you should use this structure in your project. For example you should use **MVC url pattern**, not default pattern. If you want to use plain url pattern, Why do you use mvc framework?!

I recommend you to learn more about mvc architecture and yii framework.

Comment: You have a valid point, but this does not answer the question. Rather add this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Yii effectively, all requests from your web page should go through the controller mechanism build into Yii.

You can read more about this here.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller

You will have a create a controller, which consists of one or more actions. Your web form will then send a request to invoke this action.

As an example, so you have a controller Plans that supports an action create

```
// In file protected/controllers/PlanController.php
class SiteController extends CController
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        // Put your code here to create a new plan
        echo "I am going to create your plan";
        some_other_code();
        Yii:app()->end();
    }

    public function actionShowform()
    {
       $this->render("form");
    }

}
```

You can then create a url to access the action.

```
// In file protected/views/plan/form.php
<form action="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("plan/create"); ?>" method="POST">
  <!-- form details here -->
</form>
```